# iOS: delete a build in New Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a problem in the new Itunes Connect, I don't find the way to delete a build. Now you can choose the version to send in review but if I notice an error, I reject the release and I upload another time the same version (1.0) Xcode advice me that there is a 1.0 version.
But what's the way to delete it in Itunes Connect?? help me!!!

Comment: I Have got same problem but didn't get any solution yet.

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem is only the "version" number and not the "build" number... I'll try to change only the second and I'll write if I solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the build number of your project, then archive the project, and finally upload this new build.
After you can select the newest build from the list and submit it to review

Comment: only the build number? not the version number? is it right?

Comment: Exactly, yes ! You will then be able to "identify" your build in the "Preversion" tab